# Gradle classpath leak with java-library plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am currently trying to wrestle with an issue which, as per Gradle docs, should not be happening.

I am developing a few Spring Boot projects and have created a separate git repo which houses a lot of Gradle plugins with shared build logic.

For simplicity, let's say that in there I have a plugin `my-api` which declares a dependency on Spring Cloud OpenFeign:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-library`
    // ...
}
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud", "spring-cloud-starter-openfeign", "4.1.0")
    // ...
}
```

and a different plugin `my-application` which comsumes Spring Boot:

```kotlin
plugins {
    // Version is declared in build.gradle.kts of the plugin project, and is currently "3.2.2"
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot", "spring-boot-starter")
    // ...
}
```

These plugins are published to an internal repository as well as mavenLocal.

Then, in a different repository, I am developing a Spring application as a multi-module project with two modules: `foo-application` and `foo-api`. The former depends on the latter, and they both apply their respective plugins. Both internal repo and mavenLocal are marked as plugin repositories.

The issue is that OpenFeign 4.1.0 provides a transitive dependency on Spring Boot 3.2.0. Gradle is smart enough to coerce the version into the latest of the declared ones, as shown by the output of `dependencies` task:

```
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.1.0
|    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:4.1.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.2.0 -> 3.2.2
```

However, the other one still hangs in there and pollutes my classpath:
[image]
Which is really annoying as now I have 2 sets of sources and all the Spring stuff in "Search everywhere" window is duplicated.

This goes in direct opposition to the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html):

> Dependencies appearing in the `api` configurations will be transitively exposed to consumers of the library, and as such will appear on the compile classpath of consumers. Dependencies found in the `implementation` configuration will, on the other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into the consumers' compile classpath.

I ensured that the plugin is indeed the culprit and removing the dependency "fixes" the issue. I would love to find a more viable solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue.
Both plugins in question get OpenFeign from another plugin, that applies it as an `implementation` dependency. On the api side it actually gets hidden correctly, but on the application side, which is where the `dependencies` output is actually from, it still hangs in there as a regular dependency. Now to figure out the best way to exclude those transitive dependencies on the application side only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).